# Bootstrap 4 DateTimePicker Multidate not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to get Bootstrap 4 DateTimePicker working allowing the selection of multiple dates. My code below works if I remove the 'multidate: true' line in the script. But when that line is there the date picker doesn't even display.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Here's is minimal code that replicates the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
            <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
          <!-- Include Date Picker -->
          <script language="javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"/>
      </head>
    <body>
    
      <div class="form-group ">
          <h5 class="border-bottom mb-4">Date Picker</h5>
          <div class="input-group datepicker">
              <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" name=dates placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="text"/>
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
        multidate: true
      });
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: bootstrap date picker has `multipledate` but bootstrap-datetimpicker don't have the property `multidate`. check this link for more information https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: I can't find multipledate in that link (I'd actually already looked at that before posting). If I change my code to have 'multipledate: true' it doesn't work. Per the bootstrap documentation https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#multidate multidate is the correct option. I wondered whether there was some class with jQuery but haven't been able to spot it.

Comment: but you are used bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js but actual js is bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

Comment: Thank you! First time really using bootstrap and jquery. Was going round in circles. Solution was to move to datepicker and also change version to 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use all the links properly

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    multidate: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="form-group ">
          <h5 class="border-bottom mb-4">Date Picker</h5>
          <div class="input-group datepicker">
              <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" name=dates placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="text"/>
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```